# Интерфейс List и его реализация

Tags: java, ооп, list

есть такое задание:

"Напишите класс Student, предоставляющий информацию об имени студента методом getName() и о его курсе методом getCourse().

Напишите метод printStudents(List students, int course), который получает список студентов и номер курса и печатает в консоль имена тех студентов из списка, которые обучаются на данном курсе. Для обхода списка в этом методе используйте итератор.

Протестируйте ваш метод (для этого предварительно придется создать десяток объектов класса Student и поместить их в список)."

вот как я начал:

```
public class University {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }
}

public class Student {
  private String name;
  private int course;

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  public int getCourse(){
    return course;
  }

  public void prinrStudent(List students, int course){

  }
}
```

вот к чему я пришёл изучив код Дмитрия
и почитав ресурсы на сайтах:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class University {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student = new Student();
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Student("Кот Майер Дулит", 2));
    list.add(new Student("Рилка Тон Браво", 5));
    list.add(new Student("Даман Сон Гаал", 3));
    list.add(new Student("Ци Мир Мина", 3));
    list.add(new Student("Пора Винична Шестая", 1));
    list.add(new Student("Кто-То Котэньё", 2));
    list.add(new Student("Василь Ивыч Кобзарь", 4));
    list.add(new Student("Памяти Не-Тлен", 5));
    list.add(new Student("Дыга Особо Шустый", 2));

    student.printStudent(list, 2);
  }
}

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Student {
  private String name;
  private int course;

  public Student() {}

  public Student(String name, int course) {
    this.name = name;
    this.course = course;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
  public int getCourse(){
    return this.course;
  }

  public void printStudent(List students, int course) {
    System.out.println("курс "+course);
    Iterator<Student> iter = students.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Student student = iter.next();
      if (course == student.getCourse()) System.out.println(student.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

большая просьба
прокомментировать и сказать
что плохо и что имеет место быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Student {

    private final static List <Student> STUDENTS = new ArrayList<>();

    private final String name;
    private final int course;

    public Student(String name, int course) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 59 * hash + this.course;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        final Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (this.course != other.course) return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "name=" + name + ", course=" + course + '}';
    }

    public static void printStudent(int course) {
        Iterator <Student> studentIterator = STUDENTS.iterator();
        while(studentIterator.hasNext()){
            Student student = studentIterator.next();
            if (course==student.getCourse()) System.out.println(student);
        }
    }

    public static void addStudent(Student student){
        STUDENTS.add(student);
    }
    public static void deleteStudent(Student student){
        STUDENTS.remove(student);
    }
    public static boolean replaceStudent(Student fromStudent, Student toStudent){
        for (int i = 0; i < STUDENTS.size(); i++) {
            if (STUDENTS.get(i).equals(fromStudent)) {
                STUDENTS.set(i, toStudent);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}


public class University {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student.addStudent(new Student("aaa", 1));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("bbb", 2));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("ccc", 5));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("ddd", 4));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("eee", 3));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("fff", 3));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("ggg", 5));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("hhh", 1));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("iii", 2));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("jjj", 2));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("kkk", 5));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("lll", 1));
        Student.addStudent(new Student("mmm", 4));

        System.out.println("COURSE 2: ");
        Student.printStudent(2);

        System.out.println("COURSE 3: ");
        Student.printStudent(5);

    }

}
```

Comment: Если уж сделали задание за другого человека полностью, то не поленитесь хотя бы "насытить" свой код комментариями с пояснениями - что и зачем вы делали. Вдруг человек поймёт вашу писанину и поумнеет. P.S. Я категорически против честолюбия при выполнении учебных заданий за других людей.

Comment: Контролер и представление  в модели. А как же паттерн MVC?

Comment: @Вадим Корженко а как же паттерн information expert? MVC-далеко не единственный существующий паттерн,в любом случае вы какой-то нарушите.и это при условии,что вы рассматриваете консольный вывод как view.также как можно сделать service layer,а можно в каждой модели написать методы для работы с ее полями и,кстати,последний подход канонический и наиболее соответсвует ооп.но все это не имеет никакого смысла,если учитывать,что MVC-это не GRASP или GOF, а enterprise паттерн. человек, решающий такие задачи не в состоянии его понять в принципе. так может лучше написать код, который есть шанс понять?

Comment: @Rootware я тоже против выполнения учебных заданий за других. просто для меня человек, который попытался решить и не решил, и человек, который даже не прилагал усилий - 2 разных случая. в 1, как по мне, все таки стоит помогать. а на счет комментариев... человек может задавать вопросы , а я постараюсь на них ответить. все таки это ему надо , а не мне, чтобы я комментировал каждую строчку кода. а если ему не надо, то он и читать это не будет , а просто скопирует. тогда зачем я буду тратить свое время? я все таки хочу, чтобы люди чему-то научились...

Comment: Дмитрий. код сложный и избыточный. но благодаря ему я что-то да понял. в вопросе привожу пример того что сделал основываясь на задании

Comment: @Дмитрий тут правильно вы сказали что это enterprise паттерн, а ведь java (после перехода android на kotlin) язык на котором пишут в основном enterprise и паттерн этот сейчас рекомендуют использовать как базовый для всего кода написаного на java. Я например даже столкнулся с тем что во многих лекциях после окончания курса по лингвистики идет разбор паттерна MVC а потом уже только разбор java.lang, мало того все автора рекомендуют при написании любой программы на java использовать паттерн MVC.

Comment: Плохо, что вы считаете "избыточными" переопределение методов equals, hashcode, tostring. обязательно почитайте про эти методы, а также про final. кроме того, в Вашем задании вы сами просисли реализовать методы add, delete, replace, а потом сами их убрали)) и последнее... ваш метод printStudent теперь печатает курс из аргумента метода, а имя студента в цикле. если ваша логика сработает неправильно и будут показаны студенты другого курса, то вы даже не узнаете об этом. а еще вы убрали tostring, поэтому теперь не можете просто написать так: System.out.println(student);

Comment: @Вадим Корженко в таком случае предлагаю использовать только MVC и ничего больше))) я ничего не имею против MVC, но я не совсем понял, на какие именно действия пользовательского интерфейса, представленного в виде консольного вывода, вы собрались реагировать? любой паттерн, примененный для решения задачи, которая не соответствует его целевому назначению, превращается в антипаттерн. а люди, которые учат MVC до java.lang с вероятностью 99 процентов не смогут его нормально реализовать. для начала хоть наблюдатель нужно изучить, он как-никак основа MVC... тут equals, hashcode удаляют, а мы про MVC

Comment: Прошу прощения, что вмешиваюсь, но сам подход в виде ' Student.addStudent' дает неверные представления о предметной области. Сам студент не может быть хранилищем студентов, это априори неверно вне зависимости от паттернов.

Comment: @ ezhov_da абсолютно согласен, но по изначальному условию автор вопроса выложил всего 2 класса с необходимостью реализовать методы add, delete, replace. в первом классе метод main, а второй класс, собственно, student. написать коллекцию там, где main еще более нелогично, в пределах одного класса к ней и так будет доступ (без вариантов). для корректного ответа нужен сначала корректный вопрос))